# What does this syntax mean? (Duration) -> String?

Tags: function, kotlin, syntax

I'm reading through some code that I didn't write and I've come across this instance variable within a class.

`private val t: (Duration) -> String?`

It's called later in the code by

`val str = t(<Insert Duration here>)`

What does this syntax mean in Kotlin? It's difficult to interpret the variable names, unfortunately, so I have no clue what this is doing.

Comment: As you can see by the usage of the variable, it's a type that can be called with a Duration and returns a (nullable) String: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(Duration) -> String?` is the type of the variable `t`. In particular here, it's a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types).

It means "function that takes a `Duration` as argument and returns a nullable `String`".

The other piece of code shows that the variable `t` is indeed being used as a function afterwards:

```kotlin
val str = t(Duration.seconds(3))

// which could also be written as
val str = t.invoke(Duration.seconds(3))
```